# Aligning Label inside a control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm just getting started with WPF, so this is probably a pretty stupid question. Nonetheless, I haven't been able to figure this out so here we go:

I've defined a simple custom control. For now, it's just a label inside the control and I want to align the label center both vertically and horizontally. Here is the markup I have so far:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTest.Controls.WindowTitle"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the main window, I have a DockPanel like so:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.Sandbox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:BrewDay.Controls"
        Title="Sandbox" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Controls:WindowTitle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Title Bar" Background='#FF232323' Foreground="White" Height="25"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The frustrating thing is that when I use a simple label inside the window with a Height and VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment everything looks as I expect it to. For some reason when I take that and put it into a separate control, everything stops working and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: Here is how the control is currently rendering in my application:
[image: Example]

I'm trying to position the TextField in the middle of the containing control's designated rectangle (the gray area). The fact that the label's background (gray) occupies the intended area (55 pixels high by the full width of the window) but the text itself is not centered in that area is confusing to me.

Comment: Just edited my answer, it should give you what you are looking for

Comment: When I try this, the title bar no longer spans the width of the window. It is as wide as the text. I'm guessing I need to add some kind of containing element inside the control itself and place the label inside of it?

Comment: see the latest change that I made, don't use horizontalAlignment just VerticalAlignment, HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticleContentAlignment

Comment: That has done the trick, thank you Mark. I guess I'll go back and re-read about the differences between HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you have centered it inside of your control, but you have not centered your control, there are also available to your control a VerticalContentAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment which will cause the contents of your UserControl to align the way that you are wanting. I am a little confused on how you want it to look especially since you told it to dock at the top of the DockPanel. But see if this is what you are wanting.

```
<Controls:WindowTitle DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Content="Title Bar" Background='#FF232323' Foreground="White" Height="25"/>
```

[image]